# Bootstrap navbar toggler icon color remains unchanged

Tags: css, svg, bootstrap-5

My code snippet for BS5 navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Trying to get completely changed hamburger icon at narrow screen:

x.svg (standard Bootstrap icon 'x'):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
</svg>
```

My CSS:

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url('assets/img/x.svg');
    color: #ffffff !important;
    fill: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Yes, standard hamburger icon changed to X.

No, color of new toggler icon remains unchanged - always dark. Adding .bi-x with color / fill also doesn't help. How to change the color of toggler to white?

Code sample here - https://BS5DropdownArrow.vbulash.repl.co

Comment: Since you are using the svg as a background img, not as an svg element, the path is not part of the DOM and you can't manipulate it. However if you want to change the color from black to white you can try to use a css filter like `filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @enxaneta.
Putting `filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);` works great!

Comment: just adding to this anwser.
If you want to use more colors, you can use this tool https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp which calculate the filter of any css color.

For example, #ff6900 is this:
filter: invert(46%) sepia(53%) saturate(3358%) hue-rotate(0deg) brightness(102%) contrast(107%);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just download the svg file and change it yourself, save it to your directory and use that path in the background-url property.